# can't install libheif

Tags: apt, 22.04

I can't install heif-gdk-pixbuf and libheif with the error message below on Ubuntu 22.04.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libheif1 : Depends: libdav1d6 (>= 0.1.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: librav1e0 (>= 0.5.1) but it is not installable
            Depends: libsvtav1enc1 (>= 1.4.1) but it is not installable
```

output of sources.list file

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200731)]/ focal main restricted
# deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main universe
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
deb-src http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
deb-src http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb-src http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
deb-src http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb-src http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
deb-src http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse


deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
# deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ jammy main # disabled on upgrade to jammy
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse main universe restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

output of package policies

```
╰─$ apt policy heif-gdk-pixbuf                                                                        
heif-gdk-pixbuf:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.14.2-1~22.04.sav0
  Version table:
     1.14.2-1~22.04.sav0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/blender/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
     1.12.0-2build1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages

╰─$ apt policy libheif
N: Unable to locate package libheif

╰─$ apt policy libheif1
libheif1:
  Installed: 1.12.0-2build1
  Candidate: 1.14.2-1~22.04.sav0
  Version table:
     1.14.2-1~22.04.sav0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/savoury1/blender/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.12.0-2build1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: How are you trying to install it? You are probably using some PPA, or your sources are wrong.

Comment: I see it only available for *kinetic* (& later), ie. `libdav1d6 | 1.0.0-2 | kinetic/universe | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x`  so is the package you want intended for *jammy* (22.04).

Comment: @guiverc These packages `heif-gdk-pixbuf` and `libheif` are available for jammy. But dependencies are a bit different. OP is either using a PP or sources are wrong.

Comment: i run `sudo apt install heif-gdk-pixbuf`

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: It looks OK, Now please add output of `apt policy heif-gdk-pixbuf`, `apt policy libheif` and `apt policy libheif1`.

Comment: So you've added a PPA. Why didn't you tell that? remove the PPA and all should install.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have installed a PPA `ppa:savoury1/blender` that seems to have wrong dependencies.

If you remove it by

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:savoury1/blender
```

and run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install heif-gdk-pixbuf libheif1
```

the packages should install.